Database + BTRFS killing HDDs?
A database* will generate many small writes to its storage.  If the storage is backed by a BTRFS filesystem, then these small logical writes will lead to many larger writes because of BTRFS' copy-on-write mechanism.  Can this lead to significantly shorter life spans of the disks?
I'm asking because I have such a setup* and I've seen way more hard drive failures than I'd ever expect: >3 failures of high-quality HDDs on the same system within just a year or two.
* PostgreSQL, but it shouldn't really matter.
** I know BTRFS isn't a great FS to back a database, but I thought performance was the only reason and that doesn't matter that much in this context.

While its a good question, I think you will get mainly opinion based answers.   I don't think the problem is likely to be BTRFS here.   I don't use BTRFS but I do use ZFS which is also uses COW - and I've not had any failures for many years.   I think it may just be bad luck with the drives, or maybe a vibration issue or similar?   Could it be heat related?   Are all the drives the same make, model and age?

Though SSD's have limited write cycles, even when over-provisioned, they are more likely to fail than HDD's from such use. Look to overheating, environment (e.g., power glitches, air quality...) or other cause of HDD failure.

Thanks @DrMoishePippik, @ davidgo, I've looked at various things and BTRFS still isn't the most likely, but I just realized how bad DB workloads would be on BTRFS and thought maybe there's someone who has an insight into this.

I have a (not BTRFS) database on a M.2 SSD for a more than a year with no issues.  It records dozens of sensors readings like temperature humidity and etc in addition to 50+ volt,amps,watt sensors every minute of every day.  A lot of the changes are probably buffered through the DRAM cache.
